# Altering colors for the background theme for better contrast

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, dark-mode

On StackOverflow jobs, the colors make it difficult to view the name of the company. Very poor contrast, as shown in the image below (the blue text). Hope it could be improved.
[image]

Comment: It seems fine to me, but one could say it's a matter of opinion. I noticed that putting your screen on super low brightness does affect it a little, but it's still okay, not that bad. Also, can you please provide a link to that page? So we can view it as well.

Comment: I agree that monitor brightness plays a role, but using better contrasting colors is necessary. This is part of the basics of graphic design. Ask any interaction designer. You just have to turn on the dark theme in StackOverflow's preferences and visit the jobs page.

Comment: I have dark theme on, and I don't really find the need to change it. However, it does have a status-planned, so maybe it;s just me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. This is a bug where old CSS colors are overriding our dark-theme colors. I've added this to our bug board and hope to get it fixed as soon as possible.

*Update*
Thank you again. We ended up finding multiple accounts of CSS overriding our dark-theme anchor style, so /jobs should be a bit easier to navigate in dark mode now!

For those curious, some areas affected were company page ads, saved searches, edit job preference link, and downloading resume on job applications.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Hope the improved dark theme could be extended to all StackExchange websites too. It's a relief from the bright white backgrounds.